# Extract parts of a big matrix and allocate them in new variables with loop function

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, extract

I am a total beginner in MATLAB and I hope to find some help here. I have some model prediction results for 80 individuals alltogether in one large matrix. I need to extract the data for each individual from the big matrix, assign them in a new variable/matrix, do some extra calculations and then plot certain information as needed.

To do so, I am trying to write a script with a loop function but in a complicated, or maybe more accurately: in a primitive way!

Simplified Example:
My matrix is called: All_Indi_Data .... its dimension is: 600 rows x 21 columns

```
%Column 1: grouping variable (e.g., code or ID with values 1,2,3,4,5, etc.); 
%Column 2: independent var.;
%Column 3: t;
%Column 4: OBS;
%Column 5: PRED;



i= length (All_Indi_Data);

%% First Indi.
q=1;    % indicating the ID of the indi for which I want to extract the data
j=1;    % variable added to insure writing start from the first row

for r=1:i
if All_Indi_Data (r,1)==q
  Indi_1 (j,1:21) = All_Indi_Data (r,1:21)
  j=j+1
end

end

%% Second Indi.
q=q+1
j=1

for r=1:i
if All_Indi_Data (r,1)==q
   Indi_2 (j,1:21) = All_Indi_Data (r,1:21)
   j=j+1
end

end

.
.
.
```

1) My first question is: can I allocate these data in new variables (Indi_1, Indi_2, ect.) in a more simple way with or without the loop function?!!! I would appreciate your help a lot.

2) Is there any code or any way to plot these selected parts (according to the grouping variable, e.g. data for Indi_1) from the previously mentioned big matrix without wasting a lot of time and space (wto recopying the core part of the code again and again) for the script, and using the loop function?! in other words, I would like to detect - with loop function & the grouping variable- which values are of interest and then to plot them (e.g. data in colum 3 with data from column 4 for each individual, starting from the first to the last)?!

I hope that I described my problem clearly and hope to hear something from the expert guys :) ...

Thanks a lot in advance ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
for idx=1:80
    pos=find(All_Indi_Data(:,1)==idx);
    eval(['Indi_' num2str(idx) '=All_Indi_Data(pos,:);']);
end
```

What I do is: in each iteration, I search for a value of the ID, indicated in the variable idx. Note that I do not use ´i´ as the name of a variable, because Matlab uses it and ´j´ and the imaginary unit for complex numbers and that could cause problems.

Then, using find I search for the position (or positions) of All_Indi_Data in which I can find the information of that individual. Now I have in the variable ´pos´ the indexes of the rows in which there is information for the individual of interest.

Finally, using eval I extract the data for each individual into a variable. Note that eval combined with a loop makes it easy to create lots of variables. I indicate the rows I want to extract with ´pos´ and, as I want all the columns, I use just ´:´ (you could use ´1:21´ too).

With another similar loop you can plot the information you want. For example:

```
for idx=1:80
        eval(['x=Indi_' num2str(idx) ';']); 
        % Now I have in X the information for this individual
        %Plot the columns of x I want
        plot(x(:, 3), x(:,4));
        pause; %stay here until a press a key

end
```

Comment: Oh ... Thanks a lot .. For the clear answer but also for the very fast reply ... I will try it ( i am getting  a red color by the first copy-past :p) and then I will update my answer ,,,

Comment: Update ....
I am getting this error message:


Error using horzcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Error in Test_Script (line 6)
    eval(['Indi_' num2str(idx) '=ALL_Indi_Data(' num2str(pos) ',1:21);']);


any clue>>?
I must mention that for one individual there maybe 6 or 7 information raws .. and so on .. !! 

Thanks again in advance

Comment: This is probably because it's finding the ID in more than one row. If you want the first matching row, you should change num2str(pos) with num2str(pos(1)). If you want them all... How would you like to save them? With which variable name?

Comment: Aha .. thanks .. but what if I want to have all 6 rows together? so that the new matrix will be 21 columns x 6 rows ... as a part from the big one consisting of 21 columns x 600 rows ... I want them to be saved as a new smaller matrix with the name Indi_1, Indi_2 etc. ... :)

Comment: I've edited my answer to try to make it work as you say. Hope it works for you now. Let me know!

Comment: WOOOOhooo .. god bless you, that worked perfectly :) .. thanks a lot .. I would be more than happy if you can give a look at the second question when you have some free time later on .. :) have  a nice day ..

Comment: I've added a simple example about plotting all the variables you have created. You'll have to play with it to make it plot the columns you want, but I hope it's a good starting point. Good luck! :) If you still have problems, tell me again.

Comment: Thank you very much .. the simple example you added at the end helped me also a lot ... good luck in your PhD .. :)